# Why is acos() resulting in "nan(ind)" when using the result of a dot product?

Tags: c++, armadillo, math.h

I'm very confused with the issue. The code I am running is:

```
double dotProduct = dot(A, B);
std::cout << dotProduct << std::endl;
theta = acos(dotProduct);
std::cout << theta << std::endl;
```

The output of which is

```
-1
ANGLE: -nan(ind)
```

However, the following works:

```
double dotProduct = dot(A, B);
std::cout << dotProduct << std::endl;
dotProduct = -1;
theta = acos(dotProduct);
```

Giving the output:

```
-1
ANGLE: 3.14159
```

Also, if I cast dotProduct to a float, acos() outputs the angle correctly:

```
double dotProduct = dot(A, B);
std::cout << dotProduct << std::endl;
theta = acos((float) dotProduct);
```

Also resulting in the output

```
-1
ANGLE: 3.14159
```

For the dot() function, I am using the Armadillo library. What I don't understand is why acos() should work when I set dotProduct = -1, but will not when it is outputted by the dot() function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Likely the value returned by `dot_product` is slightly greater than one, and the default format for inserting a `double` into an output stream does not show the value fully. Inserting `std::setprecision(99)` before the `double` should show it. Converting it to `float` rounds to the nearest representable `float`, which is exactly one because the value is so close to one.

Comment: If @EricPostpischil is right, you can use `dotProduct = std::clamp(dotProduct, -1., 1.);`.

Comment: (Note my “slightly greater than one” should be “slightly greater than one in magnitude.” E.g., −1.00001…)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that `A` and `B` are normalized vectors, and therefore you expect that `dot(A, B)` will be between `-1` and `1`. With floating-point math, this is not necessarily true. `|dot(A, B)|` can be slightly larger than `1`. I bet, if you print it with larger precision, you'll see that your value is slightly smaller than `-1`.

So, you'll need to clamp `dot(A, B)` between `-1` and `1`. Or even better, call `acos()` only, if the input is between `-1` and `1`:

```
double safe_acos(double value) {
    if (value<=-1.0) {
        return <pi>;
    } else if (value>=1.0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return acos(value);
    }
}
```

This could be slightly faster, as you avoid calling `acos()` for out-of-bound values.

Note: If you do 3D math, there is a high chance that you can avoid calling `acos()` altogether. Using trigonometric identities, usually we can replace it with something faster, and more accurate solution.